# HTML/CSS Div Overflows

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div overflow, but rather than create a scroll bar, make the **entire webpage** larger so as to avoid scrolling?

Comment: What do you mean by entire webpage larger?

Comment: So you want the div height to match that of the content?

Comment: please post the code that you have so far so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: One of my divs scrolls under a larger screen size. I wandered if instead of getting a scroll bar (overflow:hidden removes the extra content, I want it there), I want the element to <em>get bigger </em>but instead of scrolling, just make itself larger and ignore the fact that the rest of the page will be shorter. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid scrolling:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To make entire webpage larger:

```
min-height: <!-- set larger height -->
```

Hope it helps!